# Achieving High Availability for Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, high-availability, downtime

It is my understanding that Redshift is built for performance but not for Availability. 
The documentation https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/faqs/
suggest that once any node is down, the whole cluster is down until the node is restored. In the case of the AZ failure, you have no luck at all.

This post suggests having a double cluster 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-multi-az-or-multi-region-amazon-redshift-clusters/
however, it is not clear to me how do you replicate Looker's PDT tables to support instant failover via Route 53 to the standby cluster?

Just curious about what people do to address the HA issue on Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

from the Q&A regarding high availability in case an AZ disruption scenario:
"If your Amazon Redshift data warehouse cluster's Availability Zone becomes unavailable, Amazon Redshift will automatically move your cluster to another AWS Availability Zone (AZ) without any data loss or application changes. To activate this, you must enable the relocation capability in your cluster configuration settings." https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/faqs/?nc1=h_ls

Answer (score 0):

Redshift now supports multi-AZ deployments: https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/reliability